# Having Multiple Google Maps API in a single WebForm

Tags: javascript, asp.net, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

My objective is to have 2 google maps in definitely 2 separate divs.

1st Div:
Latitude and Longitude are retrieved from my database table into HiddenFields. Using the values from the two hiddenfields i use javascript to bring out the map.

2nd Div:
Latitude and Longitude are retrieved from a gridview table in the WebForm itself, and using the method OnSelectedIndexChanged -> i get the Cells (latitude and longitude) and then using these 2 values i bring them over the another 2 different HiddenFields then using javascript to bring out the map from the values from the gridview.

I have generated 2 separate google map api v3 keys for each purpose. After adding the codes for my 2nd div i get errors and i've read about it that u cant have 2 javascripts executing the maps.

Could i get any help with having to make these 2 maps show up? I already have the codes.. I think it'd be too lengthy if i added them.. But if requested i'll add them in.

Thank you.. Appreciate any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think Google allows multiple API keys for the same project due to reasons around quota limiting (https://developers.google.com/maps/faq#usage_mapload)

> Quota limits are enforced on a unique project basis, and you may not take any action to circumvent quota limits. For example, you may not create multiple projects to compound and exceed quota limits.

What you can do is simply instantiate the two maps:

```
const map = new google.maps.Map(someMapElement, someOptions);
const secondMap = new google.maps.Map(someOtherMapElement, someOtherOptions);
```

Where options is an object containing data (lat, lng, etc.) from the fields you detailed in your question.

Here's a quick and dirty fiddle to demonstrate two maps, with two completely different sets of data being rendered on the same page:

https://jsfiddle.net/c57x6a2d/

Comment: hey stefan.. yeah i thought so too... ugh.. is it possible if you show me an example of it? i'll upload my codes.. reason being.. shouldnt be an excuse but i've not much knowledge with js..

Comment: my first and second map is in webform 2. mapoptions for first map is derived from webform 1 from session variables. while second map is based on clicking on a row from a gridview. so basically first map mapoptions is actually load on pageload which is when all DOM elements are loaded.. will this example you provided by applicable stefan?

Comment: @domster, it sounds like it might be your job to figure out the rest. Using an API key makes no difference.